# About the roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: quadratic-forms

Let $m_1$ and $m_2$ the real and diferent roots of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Do you know some way to write $m_1^k + m_2^k$ in a simplest form (linear, for example) using just $a,b,c,m_1$ and $m_2$?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Try an internet search on the topic of *writing symmetric polynomials in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials*.  There are various algorithms for doing the job.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Newton's polynomial to calculate any value of $m_1^k + m_2^k$, without actually calculating the roots and using just the coefficients in front of the variable. Actually it works for any degree polynomial. Let $s_k = m_1^k + m_2^k$ and $m_1$ and $m_2$ be roots of $ax^2 + bx + c=0$. Then we have:

$$as_1 + b = 0$$
$$as_2 + bs_1 + 2c= 0$$
$$as_3 + bs_2 + cs_1 = 0$$
$$as_4 + bs_3 + cs_2 = 0$$
$$ \ldots$$

You can find more about the general formula and Newton's polynomials [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/PolynomialsAK.pdf).

This maybe isn't what you are, assuming that you want just linear expression, but it's recursive one and should satisfy your requirements